# Filters for table columns with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've successfully built a table with Vue which has dropdowns as the header for each column. The values for each dropdown are coming from different axios calls as arrays, and they are filled properly.

THe problem I have is that the second I filter any column it hides the whole table and there's no way to reset it to get it back. SO it's not filtering at all properly and it also doesn't go back to a 'show all' option.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
      <thead>
          <tr>    
              <th>
                  <select v-model="filters.resource">
                    <option v-for="resource in resources" :value="resource">{{ resource.name }}</option>
                  </select>
              </th>
              <th>
                  <select v-model="filters.location">
                    <option v-for="location in locations" :value="location">{{ location.name }}</option>
                  </select>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th>
                  <select v-model="filters.status">
                    <option v-for="status in statuses" :value="status">{{ status }}</option>
                  </select>
              </th>
              <th></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody  v-for="event in filtered">
          <tr>
              <td>{{ event.resource }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.location }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.status }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>


  <script>
  export default {
      data () {
          return {
              events: [],
              locations: [],
              resources: [],
              filters: {
                title: null,
                resource: null,
                location: null,
                status: null,
              },
          }
      },
      created() {
          this.fetchTasks();
          this.fetchLocations();
          this.fetchresources();
      },
      computed: {
        filtered() {
          return this.events
            .filter(event => !this.filters.resource || event.resource === this.filters.resource)
            .filter(event => !this.filters.location || event.location === this.filters.location)
        },

        resources() {
          return this.resources
            .map(resource => resource.name)
            .filter((resource, index, self) => self.indexOf(resource) === index);
        },

        locations() {
          return this.locations
            .map(location => location.name)
            .filter((location, index, self) => self.indexOf(location) === index);
        },
      },
      methods: {
        fetchItems() {
          axios.get('/items')
          .then(response => {
            this.events = response.data
          })
      },
      fetchLocations() {
          axios.get('/locations')
          .then(response => {
            this.locations = response.data
          })
      },
      fetchresources() {
          axios.get('/resources')
          .then(response => {
            this.resources = response.data
          })
      }
    },
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, don't name computed properties the same as data properties. Vue will pick up data properties instead of computed ones with the same name.

The values of `this.filters.location` and `this.filters.resource` are objects since you defined value of `<option />` as:

```
<option v-for="resource in resources" :value="resource">{{ resource.name }}</option>
```

So if user choose resource option "Resource A", the value of `this.filters.resource` would be `{ name: "Resource A" }` or something similar. And in javascript, object comparison cannot be done simply by == operator. That means the value of

```
!this.filters.resource || event.resource === this.filters.resource
```

will always be false.

Consider comparing only the name instead, i.e. `this.filters.resource.name`.

Comment: Changing all of my filtered function children to this: ```.filter(event=> !this.filters.resource.name || dateEvent.resource=== this.filters.resource.name)``` seems to break html loading. Also, will this allow me to somehow reset all filters?